# Use Qml/TypeScript instead of Qml/JavaScript

Tags: typescript, qt, qml

I was wondering if there is a way of implementing TypeScript with a Qt/Qml project ?

Any resources about that ?

Thx

Comment: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-63600